# How do I convert a string to sentence case in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

With the caveat that this is not a silver bullet, I submit this question and provide my own answer, since after a reasonable college effort, I found myself with no solutions for PostgreSQL.

The task in my case is to convert a collection of largely upper-case-only sentences into a reasonable facsimile of a paragraph using capitalization for just the first letter of each sentence. If that solution is out there, either I'm blind or it was decently well hidden.

So, for example, how do I convert

```
THE NAME IS BOND. JAMES BOND. 007. AND THIS IS ONE COOL PIECE OF CODE.
```

to

```
The name is bond. James bond. 007. And this is one cool piece of code.
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. I'd be glad to award the answer to a better solution!

```
WITH fixed_sentences_source AS (
  WITH single_sentences_source AS (
    WITH arrays_source AS (
      SELECT
        regexp_split_to_array(LOWER('THE NAME IS BOND. JAMES BOND. 007. AND THIS IS ONE COOL PIECE OF CODE.'), '\. ' ) AS arrays
    )
    SELECT TRIM(UNNEST(arrays)) AS single_sentences
    FROM arrays_source
  )
  SELECT
      UPPER(SUBSTRING(single_sentences, 1, 1)) || SUBSTRING(single_sentences, 2, LENGTH(single_sentences) - 1) AS fixed_sentence
  FROM single_sentences_source
  WHERE
    single_sentences <> ''
)
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT fixed_sentence FROM fixed_sentences_source), '. ')
```